# Create responsive photo grid that maintains aspect ratio?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have group of images arranged with Masonry. I want the images to be able to resize but I want them to stay in the same order. Basically, I want the entire grid to keep the same aspect ratio. I've tried the fluid Masonry layout option and it makes the images jump all over the place. If I set the container div to keep aspect ratio the images just jump below container on browser resize. Is there anyway to do this with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

for maintain aspect ratio you can use from this jQuery function:

```
jQuery.fn.fitToParent = function()
{
    this.each(function()
    {
        var width  = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();
        var parentWidth  = $(this).parent().width();
        var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();

        if(width/parentWidth < height/parentHeight)
        {
            newWidth  = parentWidth;
            newHeight = newWidth/width*height;
        }
        else
        {
            newHeight = parentHeight;
            newWidth  = newHeight/height*width;
        }
        margin_top  = (parentHeight - newHeight) / 2;
        margin_left = (parentWidth  - newWidth ) / 2;

        $(this).css({'margin-top' :margin_top  + 'px',
                     'margin-left':margin_left + 'px',
                     'height'     :newHeight   + 'px',
                     'width'      :newWidth    + 'px'});
    });
};
```